# If you are given an inverse DFT, then how do you convert it back to the DFT without actually computing any DFT?

Tags: fft, dft, ifft, inverse

If you are given an inverse DFT, then how do you convert it back to the DFT without actually computing any DFT?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Expressing_the_inverse_DFT_in_terms_of_the_DFT plus a bit of basic math does the trick.

Comment: Your question seems ambiguous to me. When you say "an inverse DFT" are you referring to a finite sequence of numbers or a mathematical equation? And this "DFT" thing you desire, is it a finite sequence of numbers or a mathematical equation?

Comment: I wonder, is the material at the following web site the information you seek:
https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/800.php

Comment: @RichardLyons i am referring to the sequence of numbers or signals.... This was one of my query I read in the exercise section of the book

Comment: @ElectronicsEngineer. Hi. So your question seems to be: "If you are given a time-domain sequence (an inverse DFT), then how do you compute its DFT (convert it back to the DFT) without actually computing any DFT?" Is that a correct description of your question?